# Base58Check encoding for Bitcoin addresses too long

Tags: python, bitcoin

I'm trying to create a Bitcoin address with Python. I got the hashing part right, but I have some trouble with the Base58Check encoding. I use this package:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/base58

Here is an example:

```
import base58

unencoded_string = "00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F6"
encoded_string = base58.b58encode(unencoded_string)
print(encoded_string)
```

The output is:

```
bSLesHPiFV9jKNeNbUiMyZGJm45zVSB8bSdogLWCmvs88wxHjEQituLz5daEGCrHE7R7
```

According to [the technical background for creating Bitcoin addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses) the RIPEMD-160 hash above should be "16UwLL9Risc3QfPqBUvKofHmBQ7wMtjvM". That said, my output is wrong and obviously too long. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

EDIT:

I added a decoding to hex (.decode("hex")):

```
import base58

unencoded_string = "00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F6"
encoded_string = base58.b58encode(unencoded_string.decode("hex"))
print(encoded_string)
```

The output looks better now:

```
1csU3KSAQMEYLPudM8UWJVxFfptcZSDvaYY477
```

Yet, it is still wrong. Does it have to be a byte encoding? How do you do that in Python?

EDIT2:

Fixed it now (thanks to Arpegius). Added **str(bytearray.fromhex( hexstring ))** to my code (in Python 2.7):

```
import base58

hexstring= "00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F6"
unencoded_string = str(bytearray.fromhex( hexstring ))
encoded_string= base58.b58encode(unencoded_string)
print(encoded_string)
```

Output:

```
16UwLL9Risc3QfPqBUvKofHmBQ7wMtjvM
```

Comment: Is `unencoded_string` encoded in hex? You need to decode it first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `base58.b58encode` need a bytes (python2 str) not a hex. You need to decode it first:

```
In [1]: import base58
In [2]: hexstring= "00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F6"
In [3]: unencoded_string = bytes.fromhex(hexstring)
In [4]: encoded_string= base58.b58encode(unencoded_string)
In [5]: print(encoded_string)
16UwLL9Risc3QfPqBUvKofHmBQ7wMtjvM
```

In python 2.7 you can use `str(bytearray.fromhex( hexstring ))`.

Comment: Thank you, but I get following message: AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'fromhex'. I copied you code 1:1. EDIT: Never mind, got it now. Thank you so much!